# PHP- how to convert string to number?

Tags: php

How to convert this 19,500 string to number. If I do this

```
<?php

$val = "19,500";
$number = explode("," , $val);
$newnumber = $number[0].$number[1];

?>
```

But I don't think this is correct way.

Comment: Are you only trying to remove commas? When you say you want to convert to a number, what specifically do you mean?  An integer? A float? A numeric string?

Comment: You want to remove just `,` or you want to convert to integer?

Answer (score 2):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.org/BN6qPQM8)**

You can replace the string ',' to '' and then convert into integer by `int`

```
<?php

$number = "19,500";
$updatedNumber = str_replace(',','',$number);

echo (int)$updatedNumber ;
```

***NOTE:** `int` is better to use than `intval` function.
It reduces overhead of calling the function in terms of Speed.
http://objectmix.com/php/493962-intval-vs-int.html*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$val = "19,500";
$val = str_replace(',', '.', $val);
$number = (float)$val;
?>
```

UPDATED:
if comma comes out as a thousands-separator then:

```
<?php
$val = "19,500";
$val = str_replace(',', '', $val);
$number = (int)$val;
?>
```

Comment: This depends very much on whether `,` is used as a decimal point or a thousands-separator.  In the US, your result would be off by a factor of a thousand -- even more if there were two commas.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply replace ',' with ''

```
$newnumber = str_replace(',', '', $val);
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is:

```
<?php
  $val = "19,500";
  $tmp = str_replace(',', '', $val);
  $newnumber = (float)$tmp;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to remove the `,`:

```
<?php
$val = "19,500";
$val = strtr($val, array(',' => ''));
$number = intval($val);
var_dump($number);
```

use `strtr()` instead of `str_replace()` in case of multiple `,`

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code

```
$val = "19,500";
$newnumber = intval(str_replace(',', '', str_replace('.', '', $val)));  // output : 19500

$val = "19,500.25";
$newnumber = intval(str_replace(',', '', str_replace('.', '', $val)));  // output : 1950025
```

you can edit delimiter that want to replace with balnk string :)

Or you can try this

```
$newnumber = preg_match("/[^0-9,. -]/", $val) ? 0 : preg_replace("/[^0-9.-]/", "",$val);
```

Comment: You almost never want to remove both commas *and* periods, unless what you have isn't really a number.  Doing so throws off the numeric value by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: @cHao => Question mentioned that "how to convert string to number?" then if string contain alpha numeric value, it will automatically convert to 0.

Comment: No, it'll automatically stop parsing at the first character that doesn't belong.  So `intval('19,500')` would be equal to 19.  But for integers, you *want* the decimal point (and everything after it) ignored, not interpreted as more digits.  So, `intval('19500.25')` would be equal to 19500, which is almost certainly the desired result.  Your example outputs a number a hundred times the string's numeric value.

Comment: @chao =>  Yes, you are right !!! And solution is : $newnumber = preg_match("/[^0-9,. -]/", $val) ? 0 : preg_replace("/[^0-9.-]/", "",$val);

Comment: That'd work...mostly...though it differs from the built-in behavior in that any wacky character causes the result to be 0.  I'm of two minds about whether that's a good thing.  Depends on whether that degree of strictness is called for, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

When I see your code it's just sting `string(5) "19500"`

```
<?php
 $val = "19,500";
 $number = explode("," , $val);
 $newnumber = $number[0].$number[1];
 var_dump($newnumber);
?>
```

so you can convert to integer like the following

```
<?php
    $val = "19,500";
    $number = explode("," , $val);
    $newnumber = $number[0].$number[1];
    $realinteger = (int)($newnumber);
    var_dump($realinteger);
?>
```

So the result will be `int(19500)`

Comment: What about 19,500,200

Answer (score 0):

just try one. simple as that :)

```
<?php
$val = "19,500";
$val = str_replace(',','', $val);
$newnumber = number_format($val,2);

?>
```

OUTPUT:
19,500.00

- If you want to have no decimal you can change the 2 in 0. Like this.

OUTPUT:
19,500